# Microsoft Dot NET C#

Tags: c#

```
private void LH()
    {
        int length = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int height = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        float outcome;
        outcome = (float)length / height;
        textBox3.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void LS()
    {
        int length = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int slope = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        float outcome;
        outcome = (float)length / slope;
        textBox2.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void HS()
    {
        int height = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int slope = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        float outcome;
        outcome = (float)slope*height;
        textBox1.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1 && textBox2)
        {
            LH();
        }
        else if (textBox1 && textBox3)
        {
            LS();
        }
        else if(textBox2 && textBox3)
        {
            HS();
        }
    }
```

I want to test if the values are entered in textboxes to evaluate the req function by putting IF block with condition of textbox.But when i try this it say textbox value can not be converted into bool......so tell me anyone how to test it and convert to bool

Comment: What conditions are supposed to be in `if`s? Also consider renaming your question into something more specific

Comment: Please, indeed, change the title of your question to an actual question. The technologies used are for the tags.

Comment: Your title is great. But if you want to write better, you can read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: `if (textBox1 && textBox2)` - The textBox1 is an object with properties (e.g. textBox1.Text), but you are creating logic expression that uses textBox1 itself instead of its member. As textBox1 is of TextBox type and is not boolean you got your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the textbox value is not a bool, but rather text, you need to compare it to something in order to obtain a boolean value.

If you are looking to determine if there's any text in the box, you could consider comparing it with an empty string, or using a convenience function to determine if the box is empty.

For example:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    // code here to handle empty box
}
```

Or:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textBox1.Text))
{
    // code here to handle empty box
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
}
```

Or

```
if (textBox1.Text != "")
{
}
```